# Android Logo too smal

Tags: android, icons, size

I recognized that the launcher icon for one of my app is too small.
The device is a samsung nexus galaxy, so it should use the drawables from the mdpi folder.

I want the icon size to be 72 x 72 pixels.
Actually the icon looks like small or xtra small, it is definitely smaller than all launch icons on this phone. I remember I've put lots of standard sized icons into each drawable folder. At this moment ALL folders contain the same Icon of 72 x 72 pixles (inside of bin/res/... AND the root res/... so it is improbable a bug of eclipse or the A SDK.

I deinstalled the Application, I created a new project, I switched computers, this icon is still too smal and I have no clue why.

There is nothing of interest in my manifest, that could cause this, I think.

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that your device is mdpi? Without checking, most newish devices are at least hdpi. As Geoff said, though, the size of 75 x 75 isn't right. Check here and make sure you've got all the correct sizes:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size

Comment: Both of you where right. I thought xhdpi requires a 72x72 icon. I replaced it with a 96x96 icon and it looks fantastic. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

No launcher icons should be 75x75.

Refer to the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size) to see what you should be using for launcher icon sizes.

```
ldpi:  36x36px
mdpi:  48x48px
hdpi:  72x72px
xhdpi: 96x96px
```

Comment: Geoff is right; Galaxy Nexus is XHDPI, you should be using 96x96. Putting 72x72 into all folders is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

The Glaxy nexus is an XHDPI phone for sure, so putting a 72x72 icon size in drawable-xhdpi isn't right as it doesn't respects the [Icon Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html).You should put an 96x96 icon size in drawable-xhdpi

Answer (score 0):

Here are the App icon dimensions:

```
ldpi = 36*36 pixels
mdpi = 48*48 pixels
hdpi = 72*72 pixels
x-hdpi = 96*96 pixels
xx-hdpi = 144*144 pixels
```